# Weird partition table

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I was given a hard disk to repair/extract data from. This hard drive was once the hard drive of a computer that had windows and linux installed (using grub to change between two). Booting from the hard drive is not possible anymore. When connected to linux, 4 partitions are found (`/dev/sdb[1256]`), but only `/dev/sdb1` can be read. `/dev/sdb1` is the grub-partition, while `/dev/sdb5` was identified as swap-partition by `blkid` (it might have been another program, i'll check that). Mounting the partitions 2 and 6 gives errors, `var/log/syslog` says something about a bad superblock.
<s>Still, the most irritating result gives `fdisk -l`, which prints the partition table AFAIK.</s>

```
Device    Start    End        Type
/dev/sdb1     2048  19531775  83 linux
/dev/sdb2 19533822 625141759   5 extended
/dev/sdb5 19533824  36304895  82 linux swap 
/dev/sdb6 36306944 625141759  83 linux
```

(1 sector equals 512 byte, some of the output was removed by me. I will add it if needed)

If I understand correctly, something is wrong with the partition table. Somehow partition 2 is at the same location as partitions 5 and 6, which might explain the mounting-errors. (I will ask which OS really was used on this hard drive).

Now, there are important files on this hard drive. How do I get these files from the hard drive or (better) alter the hard drive so linux can mount all partitions. My first thought was to make a backup with `dd` and then let a `fsck` run on `/dev/sdb` (You might see I am no expert at this), although I have my doubts.

**UPDATE:** As grawity pointed out, the partition table is intact and there are 3 partitions, from which one is a swap-partition. `/dev/sdb1` can be mounted and is the grub-partition (judging from the files on the partition). `/dev/sdb5` is most likely the swap-patition (since it's labeled as such and its size is in the right magnitude). I will try doing a `fsck` on `/dev/sdb6` and try some recovery tools.
Also, the person who gave me the hard drive is now thinking if he gave me the right one. I will look for the files anyway.

Comment: The only partitions here which could potentially hold data are sdb1 and sdb6 (partition info is given expertly by grawity's answer), and there are no Windows partitions here to recover data from. Although I can't say for certain, sdb1 was probably root (/) and sdb6 was probably home (/home) mounts, so the later is probably the most important. If possible, since you are getting errors, I would `dd` those 2 partitions to files, then mount the files and attempt recovery there.

Comment: "`/dev/sdb1` is the grub-partition" - No, I don't think it is. It's about 9.5GiB, which suggests it's the root filesystem (containing the OS + programs, but not the documents and media). Ok, the root filesystem would in this case _also_ contain grub, but to me "grub-partition" implies that it _only_ contains grub.

Comment: @marcelm If `/dev/sdb1` would be the root partition, there would be directories such as `bin`, `var`, `etc` and others. I just gave it a quick look but I didn't see those. I quickly decided that `/dev/sdb1` was no root-filesystem because there were many files containing "grub" in the uppermost directory. But of course this does not say I'm right, so far I have only seen a limited number of linux-distributions. I will have a proper look at it later. Thank you.

Comment: To check the drive for (possibly *brutalized*) NTFS partitions, see my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271

Answer (score 7):

> If I undmerstand correctly, something is wrong with the partition table. Somehow partition 2 is at the same location as partitions 5 and 6, which might explain the mounting-errors.

This is normal. The MS-DOS-era MBR partition table can only hold 4 partitions, so it's customary to make the last one an ["extended" partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record), in which additional "logical" partitions are nested.

(Linux always numbers the logical partitions starting with 5+, and while the names in `fdisk -l` are actually made up, they also follow the same numbering.)

*(While on the topic, don't forget that there are other partition tables such as GPT. fdisk 2.23 understands GPT, but older versions do not.)*

Also note that the partition types don't always correspond to the actual data inside. It's not impossible that the owner might have decided to use sdb5 for data and sdb6 for swap, but forgotten to update the MBR partition types (which Linux ignores, anyway).

> How do I get these files from the hard drive or (better) alter the hard drive so linux can mount all partitions

Try *photorec*.

> My first thought was to make a backup with dd and then let a fsck run on /dev/sdb

Making a backup is a good idea. Trying to run fsck on something that's *not a FS* won't do anything useful. `/dev/sdb1` or `/dev/sdb6` would be better targets for that, since they contain filesystems.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It's good to know that the partition table is ok (You learn something new everyday :) ). I will try photorec and other recovery software (there are also videos on that drive) after the backup is finished, not to forget fsck on `/dev/sdb6`.

Comment: I would suggest going with `testdisk` before carving with `photorec`. Testdisk understand file systems, so it should be tried first to get a better result.

Answer (score -1):

The partition table you displayed belongs to a  **pure** Linux system: there is no trace of Windows on it. So, given that you stated:

> This hard drive was once the hard drive of a computer that had windows and linux installed ...

perhaps the guy who gave it to you was right when he said...

> Also, the person who gave me the hard drive is now thinking if he gave me the right one.

User files are in `/home/`, which is likely to be partition `/dev/sdb6`. There is no need to use something as complex as `photorec`, and, possibly, you can restore the partition to its full, working state, in an alternative way. Can you please state exactly what error message you obtain when you try to mount partition `/dev/sdb6`? If it is only a matter of a bad superblock, this can easily be cured:

1. Check the file system with (you may have to redo this with ext2 or ext3, it is not clear from the above which filesystem was being used),

   ```
    sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sdb6
   ```
2. If the superblock is indeed corrupt, then you will get an output like

   ```
   fsck /dev/sdb6
   fsck 1.41.4 (27-Jan-2009)
   e2fsck 1.41.4 (27-Jan-2009)
   fsck.ext4: Group descriptors look bad... trying backup blocks...
   fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb6

   The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext4
   filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext4
   filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
   is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
   e2fsck -b 8193 /device
   ```
3. Let us find where the backup superblocks are,

   ```
   sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdb6
   ```

   At the bootom of a long output, you will find something like:

   ```
   Superblock backups stored on blocks:
   32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208
   ```
4. And now, lastly, fix it by replacing the defective superblock with one (anyone) of the backup ones:

   ```
   sudo e2fsck -b block_number /dev/sb6
   ```

Reboot, and you should be good to go. If not, try a different superblock. Like I said, **if** this the reason why you could not mount partition `/dev/sdb6`, all of this is a heck of a lot easier than using `photorec`, plus you will restore the disk and its partitions to their pristine state.

Comment: «there is no trace of Windows on it» You are assuming the partition table is reliable and it wasn't overwritten. It might be quite a strong assumption. Nevertheless, OP should scan the drive for NTFS leftovers. :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a superblock in NTFS (well yeah, the MFT, but it's not the same). If the OP wants to verify the presence of NTFS traces, the partition table should not be trusted blindly.

Comment: Yes, and I developed a forensic NTFS reconstruction software. That doesn't change the fact that your reliance on the partition table alone is a quite naive approach. You cannot determine that there are no traces of a NTFS file system just because the partition table does not list it. If you do not trust this (obvious) fact you can check out [Brian Carrier. *File System Forensic Analysis.*
ISBN 0321268172.](http://digital-evidence.org/fsfa/) or [Harlan Carvey. *Windows Forensics and Incident Recovery.* ISBN 0321200985.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1208511)